# Как прервать выполнение цикла for на pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, база-данных, sql

Можно ли прервать выполнение цикла for на pl/sql, если да то как? Пример:

```
for rec in (query1)
    loop
       check:=sc_user.function(query1.device);
       if check ='yes' then *прервать цикл* end if;
    end loop;
```

Comment: а что, правильно построить условие выхода в самой конструкции цикла уже не комильфо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. EXIT - Безусловный выход из цикла.
       Используется посредством применения
       оператора IF.
2. EXIT WHEN - Выход при
       выполнении условия.
3. GOTO - Выход из
       цикла во внешний контекст.

Answer (score 4):

Самый приемлимый способ прервать цикл - `exit [label] when <boolean_expression>;`. Метка не обязательна, но не рекомендуетя опускать её для лучшей читаемости. Во вложеных циклах, кроме того, она даст возможность, указать из какого цикла выходить, и различать одноименные переменные.

```
<<fetch_query1>> for rec in (query1) loop
    exit fetch_query1 when (sc_user.function(fetch_query1.rec.device) = 'yes');
       -- делать что.то с fetch_query1.rec
end loop fetch_query1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Выходить из цикла контрукцией `if-then-else` некорректно. Правильно перечислил способы [[@Crystal](/users/5874/crystal)](/users/5874/crystal), но наиболее правильный &mdash; `exit when`.
А вообще в вашем случае подойдёт цикл с условием:

```
for rec in (query1)
    while not check = 'yes' loop
        check := sc_user.function(query1.device);
    end loop;
```